# Не правильно присваиваються значения

Tags: linux, c

Есть такой код, начинаеться с **xml_get_object**, считывается символ из файла, потом буфер изменяет размер массива в динамической памяти, и присваиваются новые символы. Но текст выводиться не совсем точный, имеются не символы. Вот код.

```
static void xml_copy_text ( char *a, char *b )
{
        while ( *b != 0 ) {
                *a++ = *b++;
        }
}

static void xml_add_sym ( struct buf *buf, char c )
{
        int length = strlen ( buf->buf );
        char *a = calloc ( length + 1, 1 );
        xml_copy_text ( a, buf->buf );
        buf->buf = realloc ( buf->buf, length + 1 );
        xml_copy_text ( buf->buf, a );
        buf->buf[length] = c;
        free ( a );
}

void xml_get_object ( struct buf *buf )
{
        buf->buf = calloc ( 2, 1 );
        char *a = &buf->buf[0];
        int length = 3;
        int pos = 0;
        int ret;
        char c;
        do {
                ret = fread ( &c, 1, 1, buf->fd );
                xml_add_sym ( buf, c );
        } while ( c != EOF && ret != 0 );
        printf ( "%s\n", buf->buf );
}
```

Вот вывод.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<breakfast-menu>
  <food>
    <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
    <price>$5.95</price>
    <description>two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
    <calories>650</calories>
  </food>
  <food>
    <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
    <price>$7.95</price>
    <description>light Belgian waffles covered with strawberrys and whipped cream</description>
    <calories>900</calories>
  </food>
  <food>
    <name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
    <price>$8.95</price>
    <description>light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream</description>
    <calories>900</calories>
  </food>
  <food>
    <name>French Toast</name>
    <price>$4.50</price>
    <description>thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread</description>
    <calories>600</calories>
  </food>
  <food>
    <name>Homestyle Breakfast</name>
    <price>$6.95</price>
    <description>two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns</description>
  a�  <calories>9Q�50</calories>A�
  </food>
</1�breakfast-men!�u>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Не видно, чтобы новая строка где-либо в `xml_add_sym` завершалась символом `\0` после перевыделения памяти. До этого момента вас спасал `calloc`, который обнуляет выделенную память, но вот `realloc` *до*выделенную память не обнуляет.
2. Непонятно, зачем в `xml_add_sym` делается копирование данных туда-сюда. Зачем понадобилось `a`, выделение памяти для `a` и копирование строки в и из `a`? Функция `realloc` тем и славится, что сохраняет старое содержимое памяти. Его не надо "спасать" перед `realloc` и "восстанавливать" после `realloc`.
3. Непонятно, с чего вы взяли, что в `c` может возникнуть значение `EOF`, не говоря уже о том, что это значение `EOF` (если оно вдруг каким-то магическим образом возникнет) зачем-то посылается в `xml_add_sym`.

   (Переменная типа `char` в общем случае не может хранить значение `EOF`.)

Answer (score 0):

На беглый взгляд ошибка тут

```
while ( *b != 0 ) {
      *a++ = *b++;
}
```

в том, что вы не копируете нулевой завершающий символ. Так

```
while(*a++ = *b++);  // да, это не опечатка, никакого тела цикла нет!
```

должно быть правильнее.

А это

```
    do {
            ret = fread ( &c, 1, 1, buf->fd );
            xml_add_sym ( buf, c );
    } while ( c != EOF && ret != 0 );
```

Дополните строчкой

```
xml_add_sym ( buf, '\0' );
```

И последнее - `realloc` сам копирует все содержимое при изменении размеров...

Comment: О, точно, спасибо, ещё добавил после while, *a = 0, и все без ошибок.